# Convert pandas DataFrame to arbitrary nested JSON data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, object

Assume that I have a pandas DataFrame called `df` that looks something like:

```
source      tables      columns      
src1        table1      col1       
src1        table1      col2
src1        table2      col1 
src2        table1      col1
src2        table1      col2
```

My current code below can iterate through the list of sources and nest the list of tables within each source as an object:

```
data = [
    {k: v} 

    for k, v in df.groupby('source')['tables'].agg(
        lambda x: {v: {} for v in x}).items()
    ]

    with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent = 2)
```

The output I'm receiving with this code is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "src1": {
      "table1": {},
      "table2": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "src2": {
      "table1": {},
    }
  }
]
```

My desired output:

```
[
  {
    "src1": {
      "table1": {
         "col1": {},
         "col2": {}
     },
      "table2": {
         "col1": {}
     }
    }
  },
  {
    "src2": {
      "table1": {
         "col1": {}
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Any assistance in converting my 2-layer nested JSON file to 3 layers as shown above would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple levels of grouping here, I'd recommend just using a for loop to iterate over your data.

```
from collections import defaultdict  

def make_nested(df): 
    f = lambda: defaultdict(f)   
    data = f()  

    for row in df.to_numpy().tolist():
        t = data
        for r in row[:-1]:
            t = t[r]
        t[row[-1]] = {}

    return data
```

```
print(json.dumps(make_nested(df), indent=2))
{
  "src1": {
    "table1": {
      "col1": {},
      "col2": {}
    },
    "table2": {
      "col1": {}
    }
  },
  "src2": {
    "table1": {
      "col1": {},
      "col2": {}
    }
  }
}
```

This assumes your columns are arranged from left to right: outermost keys to innermost key.

Comment: Appreciate it. I also would only need this for the first 3 columns however as I have other columns in the DataFrame as well. Can you edit your answer to have the grouping for just the first 3 columns? Thanks

Comment: @weovibewvoibweoivwoiv pass df[[col1, col2, col3]] to the function, that should do it.

Comment: posted another follow-up question, hoping you can help answer, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60493133/how-to-nest-pandas-dataframe-converted-to-numpy-values-into-inner-most-json-ob